# How to split column layouts to specified space and to make a unscrollable container using angular nebular

Tags: angular, html, css, layout, nebular

I am using nebular theme with a fixed header and trying split columns with specified width and height.
But none seems to be working right as the column layouts are not being affected by my width and height properties in local component scss.

```
<nb-layout>
   <nb-layout-column>First</nb-layout-column>
   <nb-layout-column>Second</nb-layout-column>
</nb-layout>
```

Since I have a fixed header, the body container is again starting from the `top:0` position and hence making the body container to scroll. So here I want to make my body container not to scroll without using `overflow:hidden` to it.

I have created a stackblitz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-gv8sej

1. Please check and help me to make the first column width to occupy 70% and second to 30% in total 100% of `<nb-layout>` container.
2. How to make my home component not to be scrollable while having a fixed header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nebular layout uses Flex, therefore, use flex property instead of width.

```
nb-layout{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
nb-layout-column:first-child {
  flex: 2 !important;
  background: #e3e6f9;
}
nb-layout-column:last-child {
  flex: 1 !important;
  background: #f4f4f7;
}
```

And the scroll is caused by the following line:

```
.nb-theme-default nb-layout .layout {
   min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: even if I remove the nebular layout, scroll is added to the body. how to equally partition header and body for not to add scroll

Comment: The scroll appears when the set height is more than browser window size or content is more.